# Automate repetitive tasks for testing Purposes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I have very restricted access to the DB that I need to run my queries on which means that I cannot create stored procedures or functions. These queries are run based on the value of 4 interdependent parameters, each parameter having around 20 possible values. I was wondering if there was anyway to automate this testing so that I don't have to manually change the values of the parameters to do my testing.

The only idea I have come up with so far, which I think is a very messy one, is to put my queries in nested while loops and let the query run and output to text. This would obviously have to be after I declare some table variables/temp tables in a lot of if/else statements and use the values of those tables for the loops. However, I think this is a really primitive and messy solution to my problem but for the life of me I can't think of anything else.

Appreciate any suggestions and better solutions to this problem.

MSSQL Server 2008R2 + SSMS 2012

Answer (score 0):

Generate your queries either in another programming language or by hand, and save them in a text file. Then just run that text/query batch file against the db

Comment: Is there a pure-sql solution to this? Pretty much The only tool available to me right now is SSMS

Comment: @UbiNoob that I don't know